# parsing a file of tasks with and without ID numbers

Tags: c++, file, parsing

I have to read in a file of tasks. an example file is below.

Print_instructor_list 
Print_student_list 
Search_instructor 2
Search_student 2
Search_instructor 1

The format will not change. I am having trouble with handling how some tasks have an ID number while others don't. I thought about using a map but for both tasks and ID numbers there is the potential for repeating inputs. Are the any recommendations for how to handle this?

```
230         while (getline(myfile,line))
231         {
232             //parse line
233             string myText(line);
234             istringstream iss(myText);
235             if (!(iss>>id)) id = 0;
236             iss.ignore(1,',');
237             if (!(iss>>id2)) id2 = 0;
238             Enrollment newEnrollment(Student::studentList[id],Course::courseList[id2]);
239             Enrollment::enrollmentList.push_back(newEnrollment);
240             i++;
```

I understand how to parse ad read a file. My issue is with the fact each line of the file can contain different formatting. As in the ID number must be tied to the task. I was thinking about using a vector again. While reading the line I would check each time to see if there is a number at the end. If so I would push that int onto the end of the vector. By that I mean I read the task in and assign it to a string which is placed into the vector. Then I see if there is an int that follows the task. If so I assign that number to an int and place it into the vector.

When i have to read through the vector to get my tasks to execute, if the current index of the vector is a task that would have a ID number I would also pull the next index (i+1) and assign it to the ID variable. Then I would iterate the count +2 so as to make sure the next pass through the loop skips the index with the ID number and goes on to the next task.

Does this sound like a viable strategy or am I going about it the wrong way?

Comment: Can you please show us some coding effort?

Comment: Are you familiar with stringstream?

Comment: For this program I already have to read in files of a specific format in maps and a vector. I will post one of the sets of code to read in a file.